# 'and' condition in for loop in django template

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

Hi I want to check 2 or more conditions in a for loop inside django template. I tried -

```
<table>
                {% for p, q in products, quantity %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ p.p_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ q }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

But it did not helped and gave error -

```
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for p, q in products, quantity
```

Any idea how can I accomplish the task..??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `zip()` Python function to provide a list of tuples in your view context. Then you can loop with `{% for p, q in new_list %}` where `new_list` is the zipped lists.